# SVG hover background change in Webkit and Blink engines

Tags: html, css, svg, hover, background-color

I need to use svg icons in my new project and unfortunately I came across a problem with changing background color (:hover state) in Chrome, Safari and Opera.
The color is switching only in <use> tag and svg.icon class is ignored although hover is assigned to .icon class. Firefox works fine! 
Please check this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EeGin

Any suggestions how to fix it will be very helpful! Thanks in advance.

Comment: in Chrome the thing turns green on hover... or what's the expected behaviour?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Of course it turns green, but only background of the USE tag. The parent (.icon) should also switch the color. Check it on Firefox and you will see the difference.

Comment: Chrome and Opera both use Blink, not Webkit. And the example behaves the same for me in Opera 23, Chrome 37 (dev) and Firefox 33 (nightly).

Comment: @Erik, thanks for the detailed info about Chrome's engine and nightly builds. It seems that is common problem.